# Why does Apache Batik Rasterizer render TrueType font incorrectly?

Tags: svg, fonts, batik, truetype

I'm using [Apache Batik rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) (Java, Oracle JRE 7 on Ubuntu) to convert a SVG into a PDF. The SVG contains text and references ttf fonts, which works well, but the font [Diehl Deco](http://www.dafont.com/diehl-deco.font?text=WIR+HEIRATEN&psize=l) does not render as expected:

Expected:

[image]

Incorrect:

[image]

As you can see the "R" flows into the "A", so the kerning is not interpreted correctly as the font itself contains this information (thx to the comment from @Jongware): `R A -> -660`, `T E -> -61`

Possible solutions:

1) I think if we could exchange the font rendering engine of batik to use freetype it could work as it renders correctly in my Libre Office Writer, which uses freetype.

2) I could convert the ttf font into a SVG font, which could work better in this case of SVG to PDF rasterization. But so far I wasn't successful.

3) I could convert the fonts inside the SVG to paths, if any tools supports that propperly.

Any comments or other solutions are highly welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Most likely because Ubuntu's font renderer does not support certain *features* of the font. I'm not entirely sure what these features are officially called, but what you're looking at is something like conditional kerning, in which some letter combinations are allowed to kern differently.

Comment: Looks like it's getting the kerning completely wrong, presumably because whatever text render engine you're relying on doesn't have a full understanding of how to parse and display OpenType fonts. Find out which text engine you're using, and change it for something better.

Comment: Thx guys, ubuntu 14 does use freetype 2, which is the same osx uses afaik.

Comment: [FreeType does not support OpenType Kerning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31782261/2564301). If the font is freely available, I'll have a go and check if that's the problem here. Hold on while I check.

Comment: Okay, the problem is *not* in the font. It does contain regular kerning: `R A -> -660`, `T E -> -61`. The software in which you are using the font ("on Ubuntu" does not tell us anything useful at all) simply chose to not use kerning when displaying text.

Comment: Hey @Jongware, thx for your help and the insides! I digged deeper and found out that apache batik, which I'm using, uses [Java AWS GlyphVector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html)

I'm just not quite sure if it states that regular kerning is ignored? "The GlyphVector does not attempt any interpretation of the sequence of glyphs it contains. Relationships between adjacent glyphs in sequence are solely used to determine the placement of the glyphs in the visual coordinate space."

Comment: clarified my question with newly gained knowledge. Thx guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution worth sharing:

Batik rasterizer uses AWT GlyphVector (Java) for font rendering, which seems not capable of rendering kerning correctly - at least for this font.

I got it working as expected by converting the ttf font into a svg font via batik [ttf2svg](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html). Other tools did not work - at least in combination with batik rasterizer.

I used following command to convert the font:

```
java -jar /path/to/batik/batik-1.8/batik-ttf2svg-1.8.jar diehl_deco.ttf -o diehl_deco.svg -id DiehlDeco -l 32 -h 20000`
```

In my input svg for conversion to pdf I referenced the font via @font-faces. The id in the above command is the same as the one at the end of the font url: `#DiehlDeco`

```
<defs><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    @font-face { 
        font-family: 'diehl_deco';
        src: url('https://path/to/diehl_deco.svg#DiehlDeco') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
]]></style></defs>
```

The option `-l 32` is essential - at least for this font - as the first 32 unicode characters are not compatible with batik rasterizer. If your font does not render at all a single character in the svg font can be the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to support,all Unicode in a given fonts?